# Submit form to popup window?

Tags: javascript

I have a script that submits a form to a popup window but instead of displaying the form's action (process.php), it displays nothing (blank window). Heres my script:

```
function redirectOutput() {
var myForm = document.getElementById('formID');
var w = window.open('about:blank','Popup_Window','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusb
ar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300,left = 312,top = 234');
myForm.target = 'Popup_Window';
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It works, but you have a newline suddenly in your `window.open`.

This works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/N3YSG/.

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('formID');
myForm.onsubmit = function() {
    var w = window.open('about:blank','Popup_Window','toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=400,height=300,left = 312,top = 234');
    this.target = 'Popup_Window';
};
```

Comment: pimvdb +1 Also, you're not actually submitting the form, just setting the target. You still need to submit it.

Comment: Well im calling it from within another function by simple saying `redirectOutput();`

Comment: @Jonah Katz: So you want to submit the form manually? Because you somehow have to code that. Like `myForm.submit()`.

Comment: Added that and myForm.target = 'Popup_Window'; and it worked!

Comment: Is `Popup_Window` target in the (horrible) HTML specs? I don't see it here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form. Is this working on all browsers?

Comment: @user2173353 the `window.open` creates the popup, the 2nd argument is its name. The `form.target=name;` tells the form that it should display its results in the window with that name.

Comment: 404 on the link !

Answer (score 14):

An easy way to submit form in popup window:

HTML:

```
<form action="..." method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
    <!-- form fields etc here -->
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function target_popup(form) {
    window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
    form.target = 'formpopup';
}
```

Source:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/post-form-popup-window-javascript-jquery/

Comment: just to clarify, the "action" parameter inside the form tag is the page to which the data will be submitted, in this case `action="..."`, which would be something like `action="myPost.php"`. And the first parameter of window.open being `''` is equivalent to `'about:blank'`, and what it does is opening a blank window.

Comment: This was the best answer for me because the previous didn't allow tu be used in multiple form page. With this, with small code, like 6 forms in the same page opens in a popup when sumbitted. Thanks very much!

Comment: As I have written in the comments of the accepted answer : Is `formpopup` target in the (horrible) HTML specs? I don't see it listed here : http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form. Is this working on all browsers?

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you just do it inside of the `<form>`?

```
<form target="_blank">...</form>
```

Comment: This way it will submit most likely to a new tab where you can't set the window dimensions.