# How to submit form to new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to insert a form dynamically using JavaScript and then submit it and open target in new window.

Here is my code:

```
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.setAttribute("method", "post");
            form.setAttribute("action", xxx);
            form.setAttribute("onsubmit", "window.open('about:blank','Popup_Window','scrollbars=yes,width=550,height=520');");
            form.setAttribute("target", "Popup_Window");

            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
```

This code works -- it inserts the form dynamically and submits the form successfully. However, the form is opened in a new tab whereas I want it to open in a new window. Any idea what is up? Any suggestions on how to fix this? I'm open to jQuery as well.

Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not sure why people are marking this as duplicate. Yes, it is on the same topic as the other question but the answers are not related -- the claimed duplicate issue had a new line that was messing up the code, I don't but my code still won't work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Submit form to popup window?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353838/submit-form-to-popup-window)

Comment: @Danziger How is this a duplicate? Yes, it is on the same topic as the other question but the answers are not related -- the claimed duplicate issue had a new line that was messing up the code, I don't but my code still won't work...

Comment: what you say and what code does are two different things. A) form Doesn't get inserted anywhere. B) Form isn't opened in a new window,  the redirected url upon submission, aka results, is opened in the new window.

Comment: if anybody looking for an html answer check this -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/179015/9573341

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've marked this as duplicate because I thought your problem was about how to send a form to a popup window. Here is how to do it without using the `onsubmit` event:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", xxx);

function submitToPopup(f) {
    var w = window.open('', 'form-target', 'width=600, height=400, any-other-option, ...');
    f.target = 'form-target';
    f.submit();
};

document.body.appendChild(form);

submitToPopup(form);
```

So instead of using the `onsubmit` event to create the popup from there, you create it first, just before sending the form, and then send the form to it.

Answer (score 5):

**[You could do this instead [link]](http://jsfiddle.net/qqzxtk67/)**,

1. open a new window
2. insert form in it
3. make it submit
4. which will navigate to url

   ```
   var form = document.createElement("form");

   form.setAttribute("method", "post");
   form.setAttribute("action", "http://www.yahoo.com");


   function popitup() {
       newwindow = window.open('', 'name', 'width=800,height=600');
       if (window.focus) {
           newwindow.focus()
       }
       newwindow.document.body.appendChild(form);
       newwindow.document.forms[0].submit();
       return false;
   }

   popitup();
   ```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just edited your code to remove the `url` parameter from popitup.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, most browsers and ad blockers will block this kind of script from opening a new window because it is autorun. However, if you implement it like this where the user must click a link: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pf8Rw/182/) it is more likely to open in a new window.

Using jQuery:

```
$('.open-popup').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "");
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    window.open(this.href, '_blank', 'width=300,height=200');
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="about:blank" class="open-popup">Click Me</a>
```

Also, some browsers have preferences that disable opening in a new window automatically. So you may want to explore alternatives or simply ask users to open the link in a new tab.

Comment: It actually is already in an on.click handle -- I only showed the snippet of the code that I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to always keep a popup "focused" you can use a trick originally found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776480/3254405). By rapidly open/close/open it we ensure it's always behaves like new window and grabs focus.

```
 <form name=f1 method=post action=test.html>

  <input type=text name=name value='123'>

  <input type='submit' value='Submit' 

  onclick="if(window.open('','reuse_win') != null) {
       window.open('','reuse_win').close();
    }; this.form.target='reuse_win'; return true;">

</form>
```

Also works with a link.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="
if(window.open('','reuse_win') != null) {
   window.open('','reuse_win').close();
}" target="reuse_win">Always opens in the same window and FOCUS</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

for security reasons I needed something similar. I have to block the GET method and only allow the POST method so to display a PDF inside a popup window I used this code:

- url: is a url to show.
- mywindow: name of window.
- parameter:'width=300,height=200' size

  ```
    var windowopen = function(url,mywindow,parameter) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute("method",'POST');
    form.setAttribute("action",url);
    form.autofocus=true;
    function popupw(f){ 
        var mypopup = window.open('',mywindow,parameter);
        f.setAttribute("target", mywindow);
        document.body.appendChild(f);
        f.submit();
    }
    popupw(form);
  ```

  };

Answer (score 0):

If you mean new tab. Edit your code by add target attribute to form and delete popup target section.

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
form.setAttribute("method", "post");
form.setAttribute("action", xxx);
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```