# POST one _fixed_ variable to popup window

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, popup

Simple question. Yet managed to spend the whole day on it and still no result. Researched S.O., Google. Countless postings. Yet none of the questions are to the point I am struggling with. Any good soul that can help answer the following question.

All I want to do is POST a single *predefined/fixed* variable to a POPUP window via  clicking on an image. Again, no arrays, no dynamics, nothing else involved. Just a *predefined/fixed* variable value. That is all. I do have a working solution that gets it done via a GET, but it does not suit my needs. Therefore am on a continuous and seemingly long hunt for a solution using POST method.

mainpage.php

```
<form method="post" action="popup_page.php" target="popup" onclick="window.open('popup_page.php','name','width=600,height=400')">
<button type="submit" name="flower" value="lotus"> 
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Sacred_lotus_Nelumbo_nucifera.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="lotus"></button>
</form>
```

To validate if the variable "flower" (with the pre-defined answer of "lotus") comes through, I check it on popup_page.php by doing:

popup_page.php

```
<? echo $_POST['flower']; ?>
```

And of course no variable ever makes it to the popup page. Can anyone help what am I missing in my code? Or is my whole setup wrong altogether? Really appreciate anyone help in advance!!

Comment: Try adding an `<input type="text" name="flower" value="lotus"/>` and remove the submit button name.

Comment: Thank you, Phiter. I would like to keep the page free of text-fields.  Also, forgot to add the "Popup" page attempt. It is added now to my example. That is the main thing also - the popup_page.php needs to be a popup page, not simply a new tab.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form to popup window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353838/submit-form-to-popup-window)

Comment: Or, Peter, what do you mean by "adding" the line you suggested? Do I literally add it to the existing lines?

Comment: Ignore what I said. The post request should work, but to a popup window it's kinda different. Check the duplicate question.

Comment: Thank you, Phiter. Just looked at it, though not sure how to interpret it fully. Just a beginner at this. :-( Will try various combinations of this in any case. Though somewhat doubtful if I will succeed at it. But will try now..

Comment: Brilliant! One referenced link (on the "duplicate question page") got me to the solution. Thank you very much, Phiter, for answering so quickly and getting me to the right answer. I will post the FULL answer for everybody´ else benefit as well.

Comment: If it is a duplicate question rather delete the question than generating extra clutter on S.O.

Answer (score 0):

1. POST the value to server

   `<form action='popup_page.php' method='POST'>
   <input type='hidden' name='flower' value='lotus'></input>
   <button type='submit' value='Submit'></button>
   </form>`
2. Get value on server and echo back popup

   `<?php
   if (isset($_POST['flower'])) {
       echo '<script>alert("'.$_POST['flower'].'")</script>';
   }
   ?>`

Comment: Thank you, JohannStrauss, for answering. Your solution works as well. However I had missed adding the requirement of new page needing to specifically be a _popup_ page. Not a standard new tab/new window. Thank you in any case, though for kindly taking time and answering!! Very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phiter, who directed me to the duplicate page. Final missing pieces were found here:
https://www.electrictoolbox.com/post-form-popup-window-javascript-jquery/

So the full answer below (successfully posting a predefined variable specifically to a *Popup* page, not just a regular new tab/page).

mainpage.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function target_popup(form) {
        window.open('', 'formpopup', 'width=400,height=400,resizeable,scrollbars');
        form.target = 'formpopup';
    }
</script> 
<form action="popup_page.php" method="post" onsubmit="target_popup(this)">
<button type="submit" name="flower" value="lotus"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ed/Sacred_lotus_Nelumbo_nucifera.jpg" width="200px" height="200px" alt="lotus"></button>
</form>
```

popup_page.php

```
<? echo $_POST['flower']; ?>
```